# Android How to sort data that i retrieve from Database

Tags: android

I already have a code that get the Data from Firestore Database, the data consist of Date,Invoice numb, item type, qty and price. What i want is when i show it to recyclerview, the data is sorted asscendingly based on the invoice number. anybody know how ? thanks

```
private void filterSearch() {
        pbloading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        String filter = filterDate.getText().toString();
        FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        db.collection("sales").whereEqualTo("date",filter).get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                Log.d(Tag.ITEM, document.getId() + "=>" + document.getData());

                                String invoice = document.getString("invoice");
                                String date = document.getString("date");
                                String type = document.getString("type");
                                Integer qty = document.getLong("qty").intValue();
                                Integer price = document.getLong("price").intValue();
                                sales = new Sales(invoice, date, type, qty, price);

                                salesList.add(sales);
                            }
                            adapter = new SalesAdapter(SalesHistoryActivity.this, salesList);
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                            pbloading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        } else {
                            pbloading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            Toast.makeText(SalesHistoryActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Log.w(Tag.ITEM, "error getting documents", task.getException());
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like the following.

```
for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
   // ....
   salesList.add(sales);
}

Collections.sort(salesList, new Comparator<Sales>(){
    public int compare(Sales lhs, Sales rhs) {
      return lhs.getInvoice().compareTo(rhs.getInvoice());
    }
  }
);

adapter = new SalesAdapter(SalesHistoryActivity.this, salesList);
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 4):

Use Firebase's [orderBy()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query#order-by) method.

> Creates and returns a new Query that's additionally sorted by the specified field, optionally in descending order instead of ascending.

add `.orderBy("invoice", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)` to your query.

```
db.collection("sales").whereEqualTo("date", filter).orderBy("invoice", Query.Direction.ASCENDING).get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                //...
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem while retrieving Image URLS from firestore in a sorted order, So in order to achieve that I had use my own logic.

Step 1: I had to make sure that my keys were in order. The retrieval only orders them by value NOT the keys. Step 2: The following code is pretty self explanatory. It gets the keys and sorts them and then another loop adds the sorted key Item to another list that is sorted

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(collection).document(doc[0]).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.getResult() != null) {
                ArrayList<String> urls = new ArrayList<>();
                ArrayList<String> desc = new ArrayList<>();
                DocumentSnapshot doc = task.getResult();
                Map<String, Object> map = doc.getData();
                Object[] keysArray = map.keySet().toArray();
                ArrayList<String> keysList = new ArrayList<>();
                for(Object key : keysArray){
                    keysList.add((String)key);
                }
                Collections.sort(keysList);

                for(String key : keysList){
                    urls.add(doc.getString(key));
                    desc.add(key);
                }
                viewPager2.setAdapter(setupViewPager(urls, desc));
                styleViewPager();
            }
        }
    });
```